# WPF Datagrid Slow Performance

Tags: wpf, performance, datagrid

I'va a problem with Datagrid performance where I grouped my ObservableCollection.
There are about 3500 items in my datagrid, and the display is very very long... (about 1 min).
I've tried without the GroupDescriptions and it works fine.

So, after researches, I've tried to set EnableColumnVirtualization and EnableRowVirtualization to True and realiez my binding asynchronous (IsAsync = True) without result.

Do you have any ideas to help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Standard WPF datagrid? That one that is not really optimized for a lot of data ;(?

Comment: Add the Xaml declaration for the grid

Comment: I think grouping breaks virtualization

Comment: This is a known issue in WPF 4.0. I think it has been fixed in WPF 4.5. Try updating the target framework version.

Comment: I cannot use .NET 4.5. However, I think it's possible to optimize performance if I created two ViewModel (One for Group and an other for item) and use differents dataTemplates for the representation. Do you think that it's possible ?

Comment: I am currently having the same issue, but mine is loading in 6 minutes, how did you manage to fix it?